# Anyone having issue with Aug 2019 Windows 7 update KB4512506?

Tags: windows-7

My Asus Vivo Mini PC keeps going into a recovery mode, tries to fix itself, unable to, then boots normal, windows update notice of the update, keeps going through the same process over and over.

Others are saying to install KB4490628, but my system says its already there.

Also, I can not uninstall KB4490628 to re-install it. Windows does not give me the option on this update.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

> I can not uninstall KB4490628 to re-install it. Windows does not give me the option on this update.

[KB4490628](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4490628%20) is a  Servicing Stack and it cannot be uninstalled.  Even if you were to uninstall it, the problem you describe, is a known issue with the version of Symantec Antivirus or Norton Antivirus you currently have installed on your system.  **In other words, uninstalling and then reinstalling this required update (KB4490628), would not resolve your problem.**

[KB4474419](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4474419) is also required in order to install updates signed by SHA-2 certificates.  **You should make sure you have all Windows 7 updates installed, except those that have been released in August 2019 updates (exluding KB4474419 since it was actually updated in August 2019).**

> Others are saying to install KB4490628, but my system says its already there.
>
> Any ideas?

This is a known issue with this particular update.

> **Known issues in this update:**
>
> Microsoft and Symantec have identified an issue that occurs when a device is running any Symantec or Norton antivirus program and installs updates for Windows that are signed with SHA-2 certificates only. The Windows updates are blocked or deleted by the antivirus program during installation, which may then cause Windows to stop working or fail to start.
>
> **Workaround:**
>
> Microsoft has temporarily placed a safeguard hold on devices with an affected version of Symantec Antivirus or Norton Antivirus installed to prevent them from receiving this type of Windows update until a solution is available. **We recommend that you do not manually install affected updates until a solution is available.**

Source: [August 13, 2019—KB4512506 (Monthly Rollup)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4512506/windows-7-update-kb4512506)

Answer (score 1):

There is a known problem with the August security rollup KB4512506.  Upon restart after installation on some system -- notably, select systems that use UEFI booting -- there is a failure to boot, followed by a system restore, and the process repeats.

One option is after the system reboots after a restore/reboot is to mark the patch hidden, so that the OS stops attempting to install it, and wait for Microsoft to figure out how to fix the patch.

Another option is to let the patch install, then on reboot boot the OS installation DVD and manually replace several system files.  The latter process is documented by Brad Grorud in his August 16 reply to this post:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/security-update-kb4512506-leads-to-bootbcd-error/8f97ba71-6da8-44be-9478-7542312b39bd

Comment: These seems to be exactly what is happening to me, my little asus uses UEFI booting. This was on a 6tb hard drive and now that drive wont boot at all. I ended up using a smaller SSD with windows and then put the 6tb in an external enclosure. This way when MS does something to blow the OS I won't have to worry about all the other data on my drive.

Answer (score 1):

The KB4512506 that fails to install on so many machines Hopefully isn't due to the fact that MS will not provide support or updates for the Windows7 in the very near future. I've tried everything and am tired of seeing the 80073701 error code. Wish I could help here. I think MS is saying upgrade. That unfortunately is the way they operate business. :(

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: If you haven't already done so, install KB3133977 first, restart the machine, then try KB4512506 again. Worked for me.

Not so Short Answer: I have two i5 machines (one called i51, the other i52), both Win 7 SP1, neither have Norton's/Symantec installed. Both have the Servicing Stack updates installed. Neither is set to run Windows updates automatically. The i51 is my operational machine, the i52 gets hauled out of the cupboard every 3 months and is updated to closely mirror the i51 (an expensive backup).
KB3133977 originally appeared as an optional update. It was hidden on the i51 machine, and still is, with no issues. When updating the i52, and after having installed the other listed available updates, the August rollup KB4512506 failed, the machine went into Repair Mode and restored to the point immediately before the update, and the update was not installed. Twice. KB4512506 was hidden, which resulted in the July rollup KB4507449 being shown as available – this installed OK. A subsequent attempt at installing KB4512506 again failed. KB3133977 was then installed on the i52 machine. KB4512506 then installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

MS Update KB4512506 crashed my Windows 7 system in a big way.  The system was no longer able to find the boot device.  Fortunately I had a very good SSD backup system in place and, after several days of frustration, was able to track it down to this particular update.  I am running Norton Security, but after reading this I'm just going to wait for the two companies (Symantec and Microsoft) to work this out.  Meanwhile I will keep that update hidden.  Hopefully when it is resolved they will let us know how to move forward from here...but probably it will be up to us to figure out what to do.  I know that I will never do an update without doing a full bit-by-bit OS drive backup again!